# For loop generating numbers with asterisks

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I need to do a simple `for` loop to make it look like this in the end:

```
1****** 12***** 123**** 1234*** 12345** 123456* 1234567
```

So far, I wrote:

```
for (i = 1; i <= 7; ++i) {
    document.write(i);
    for (j = 1; j < 7; j++) {
        if (j <= 7) {
            document.write("*");
        } else {
            document.write("&nbsp");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Layout your code correctly. You'll find it makes it much easier to read. What exactly are you stuck on?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a homework post.

Comment: @Mr_Green there is [nothing wrong with asking homework questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) so this isn't a valid close reason.

Comment: @Liam thanks understood. :)

Comment: Did you mean `&nbsp;`? `&nbsp` doesn’t produce a space.

Comment: @Xufox Somehow it does provide the space (I tested it)... No clue why.

Comment: A most Simplest question to be solved by a new learner of loops on their own to get to know about how loop works and how we can play with loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there:

```
for (i = 1; i <= 7; ++i) {
    for (j = 1; j <= 7; j++) {
        if (j <= i)
            document.write(j);
        else
            document.write("*");
    }
    document.write("&nbsp;");
}
```

Your code with comments:

```
for (i = 1; i <= 7; ++i) { // This for should loop over your blocks
    document.write(i); // Doing this will make the first number change for every block.
    for (j = 1; j < 7; j++) {  // This for should loop over your numbers
        if (j <= 7) { // This if is only there for the space? Put it in the other loop!
            document.write("*"); 
        } else {
            document.write("&nbsp");
        }
        // Here you should check if you want a * or a number. Not the check to see if you want a space or not.
    }
    // Space should be here.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need another variable to hold the numbers iterating in the loop.

```js
for (i = 1, k = ""; i <= 7; ++i) {
  k += i;  // concatenating i variable values in k variable
  document.write(k);
  for (j = i; j < 7; j++) {
    document.write("*");
  }
  document.write("&nbsp");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not far off, couple of changes should do it:

```js
for (i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
  for (j = 1; j <= 7; j++) {
    if (j <= i)
      document.write(j);
    else
      document.write("*");
  }
  document.write("&nbsp");
}
```

Comment: that results in `1****** 2***** 3**** 4*** 5** 6* 7` - you are not far off either

Comment: @JaromandaX: Yeah... can I start today again please?

Comment: winner winner chicken dinner :p `can I start today again please?` what does this even mean?

Answer (score -2):

Try this:
First of all you have the main loop that runs from 1 to 7,
then you have second loop that writes your strings,
so starting from 1 until i you are writing numbers then adding **
Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xrkpspfr/11/)

```
 for (i=1;i<=7;i++)
{
     for(j=1; j<=i; j++)
    document.write(j);
    {
       while(j<=7)
       {
           document.write("*");
           j++;
       }
           document.write("&nbsp");
    }
}
```

Comment: that results in `1* 12* 123* 1234* 12345* 123456* 1234567` so, don't even try

Comment: @Liam - it runs just fine - wrong result

Comment: @Liam This is not invalid JavaScript.

Comment: @Liam No, it’s not.

Comment: Now also added a jsfiddle

Comment: @Liam It’s not a “qwerk” of JS, it’s _specified_ to be valid. There’s a difference between syntactic and semantic errors.

Comment: @Liam, it's valid. The document.write after the for is runned `i` times. The block after, with the while in it, does not need the {} around it. Here, I reformatted the exact same code to be more clear: https://jsfiddle.net/rfnqg2o3/